# Save/log HTML-Object into the file

Tags: javascript, html

Would it be possible to implement google-analystics like feature, which on page load would append the existing file located on the server with the current href? Is this achievable with js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is achievable with JS. but if you're thinking of doing it only with client side JS (presumption), that won't work, you need to have a server.

Only server side code would have the right access to add contents to a file on server.

Comment: This should be comment i think!

Comment: @BhavikKalariya yeah, I thought of adding a comment, I wasn't sure about the word limit. Thanks though. I'll look it up for later.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to obtain.

If you just want the user to save some data available on the shown page you can obtain a similar risult with a trick without server side code.

Here's a small example using jQuery:

```
var fileContent = "test";

var encodedUri = encodeURI(fileContent);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "my_data.csv");
document.body.appendChild(link); // Required for FF

link.click(); // This will download the data file named "my_data.csv".
```

If, on the other hand, what you need is specifically file manipulation on the server then my suggestion is to use node.js or any other server technology to achieve such a result.

Comment: Hi @revaljilji please accept my answer and / or upvote it in case it was useful for you

Comment: Your answer wasn't what I was looking for

Comment: @Pitto You are constantly pestering users to upvote and accept your answers. Just stop.

Comment: I am not pestering none, I have countless answers in which I've put time / effort that have zero feedback from OP. Is my time totally useless? As you see we finally got a feedback @skomisa